# Why is XML not HTML used for UI in Android progrmming?

Tags: android, user-interface

Why can't HTML be used for building interface in Android Programing?

Answer (score 6):

XML enables us to create custom tags.. Consider we created a custom view, we can reference them from xml itself. So the idea of UI separation from logics, stays intact.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a standard designed to display web pages. The android XML layout files are custom configuration files that are intended to be parsed by the dalvik VM. Two separate worlds. Here are some good reasons not to use HTML to define a configuration.

1. HTML is not well formed. Parsing is a pain. No schema checking.
2. How will you style elements ? CSS ?
3. Its hard enough getting CSS to work
   across several browsers.
4. How will you introduce custom elements into
   the HTML configuration ?

I could go on. It just does not make sense to configure a native UI using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think the xml is chosen because the xml tags are defined in android according to the UI framework classes and the attributes are defined corresponding to the member variables of the class in the UI framework. This mapping was not possible for the html.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are few reasons for that:

- When you have **Layout** and **Source Code** separately you can separate your application logic. Thus many XML files can be bound with one piece of source code and Platform (Android, Windows Phone, etc.) will choose automatically the proper XML layout depending for example on: **screen denisity**, **screen orientation** etc.
- Next thing is answer to your question: Why not html. **In my opinion** there are few reasons. Most important is that XML has **strict well formed structure** and XML can be restricted with **XML Schema**. In fact having XML Schema is great because not also restrict your document but also give an sort of **documentation** of files inside XML. Someone reading this may think: HTML can have also strict structure as XHTML specification. Yes but XML is designed for that.
- Next aspect is that XML is more popular as HTML in configuration/Layout (Java EE, XAML, Android XML's, etc.) stuff. It's like a good practise.
- In fact you can build your application almost in HTML/JavaScript but you need to use some specific framework which wrappes your Platform application and transform it to Platfrom Independent Web Application(for example Sencha Framework)

Answer (score 0):

**Extensible** Markup Language, the extensible part makes it much more versatile. HTML is basically an implementation of the general concept of XML specifically for web browsers.

Also it is overly bloated for the simple task of creating layouts because it contains a lot of tags and attributes (i.e. `method`, `onclick`, etc.) that define the behavior of elements not just their layout.