# XML Android vs Html 5 performance and concerns?

Tags: java, javascript, android, xml

Im creating a project which its based on Android Sensors. We are creating an specific "cool" design for the application.

Already I can connect several sensor which trigger javascript function when JAVA call them. To be fair all computation happens in JAVA and only the render part is via HTML and javascript via `Webview`

This Android project has some particularities:

1.- Is almost none input from the user, more than ←, →, ↑, ↓, (back button) in a DPAD (custom control) 
2.- So I dont need nothing like swipe over an specific element, or click etc.
3.- Is a controlled environment is always be the same platform over the same android version and never cross platform, never web, never IOS as example. 
4.- Fix screen size

So my question is: Is any problem using the `Webview` control instead of xml? (performance, etc), are we going to have any future problem with this approach?

NOTE: We are using HTML5 because our team is strong experience with web development and the time constrain is big for learn from scratch XML, also we are new in the world of Android Applications.

Research a little bit ([Why is XML not HTML used for UI in Android progrmming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006450/why-is-xml-not-html-used-for-ui-in-android-progrmming)) But dont include if is better performance or something specific.

Comment: "We are creating an specific "cool" design for the application." -- whether you think it is "cool" is irrelevant. What your *users* think is what matters. "Is any problem using the Webview control instead of xml?" -- your #1 concern should be user expectations. If your users are expecting a native UI, they may not think that using a `WebView` is "cool", regardless of your design. "the time constrain is big" -- you seem to think that your solution will be faster to develop. Unless you are using an existing hybrid app container (e.g., PhoneGap), I am skeptical that it will be faster.

Comment: @CommonsWare the user will not see the difference between the xml design and the html design, because will only render the "screen", actually I connected several sensor via JAVA not really complicated, and pretty much I have plenty experience with Javascript and CSS3 so building a working prototype with JS and CSS will be by far more quick for our team.

Comment: "the user will not see the difference between the xml design and the html design" -- the user will be comparing your app with other apps that the user uses.

Comment: @CommonsWare No they will not because the user will not interact with my device Im using Android only as OS not as hardware device (cellphone), they will never notices the difference. They only will see the design from my design team render in front of them in a screen. They only can use a DPAD custom input with up, down, right, left control..

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this (coming from my experience at Snapstick,  a cross platform application platform where we used embedded webviews):

Yes the performance takes some hit. When you are interacting with webviews and native java, you are adding another layer of indirection,  which has some penalty. For eg when you are passing sensor data to webview, you will serialize/de serialize data. Now the impact of this varies from application to application and the tolerance your application has for this. In our case we found it had serious impact on realtime gaming.
Also prior to Android kitkat webviews lacked serious support for html5 and also the canvas based drawing lacked support for hardware acceleration ( or had poor support, dont remember exactly), so again a performance penalty.

And as far as future proof, why would it concern you? Since your target device and platform are fixed. Isn't it going to remain unaffected by change in webviews?

Also take a look at Apache Cordova if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks man, this is a good answer, I will take in count everything. And you right I have to no be worry about "future" because is a control platform.